# How can I do a $.each in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cordova

For the last few days ive been trying to send out a list of all product names using jquery. This is what I have but it returns undefined or gives the stuff above it.

```
var ech = data.categories[0];
console.error(str)
$.each(ech, function (idx, obj) {
console.log(obj.packages)
});
```

This is the json file:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 920353,
      "order": 0,
      "name": "Packages",
      "only_subcategories": false,
      "subcategories": [],
      "packages": [
        {
          "id": 2410095,
          "order": 0,
          "name": "Account Unban",
          "price": "20.00",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2629288,
          "order": 0,
          "name": "Test",
          "price": "0.99",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 920903,
      "order": 2,
      "name": "Popular",
      "only_subcategories": false,
      "subcategories": [],
      "packages": [
        {
          "id": 2410111,
          "order": 1,
          "name": "Donate",
          "price": "5.00",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i make it display the product names of "Account Unban" and "Test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually want to do is for over all the `categories` (as it's an array) and not go all the properties of the first item you have in the `categories` array:

```
var ech = data.categories;
$.each(ech, function (idx, obj) {
```

Check the following:

```js
var data = {
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 920353,
      "order": 0,
      "name": "Packages",
      "only_subcategories": false,
      "subcategories": [],
      "packages": [
        {
          "id": 2410095,
          "order": 0,
          "name": "Account Unban",
          "price": "20.00",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2629288,
          "order": 0,
          "name": "Test",
          "price": "0.99",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 920903,
      "order": 2,
      "name": "Popular",
      "only_subcategories": false,
      "subcategories": [],
      "packages": [
        {
          "id": 2410111,
          "order": 1,
          "name": "Donate",
          "price": "5.00",
          "sale": {
            "active": false,
            "discount": "0.00"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
var ech = data.categories;
$.each(ech, function (idx, obj) {
    console.log(obj.packages)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow. How would I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Is it related to the original question?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you want to display all package names for every category.
If so, you need a second (and nested) $.each, as follows:

```
$.each(data.categories, function(idx, obj) {
$.each(obj.packages, function(idx, pack) { console.log(pack.name); });
});
```

Otherwise if you need the package names just for the first category, then:
    $.each(data.categories[0].packages, function(idx, pack) { console.log(pack.name); });